# Amazon Route 53 - Registered Domains not appearing for IAM users

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-route53

In Route 53 the registered domains will appear under the root account but will not display under IAM user accounts.
Is this expected?

Thanks
Damien

Comment: Do the IAM users have permissions for Route53?

Comment: The IAM users have Administrator access and also AmazonRoute53FullAccess

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, it is expected. On AWS, users do not have access to anything by default. Administrators have to assign IAM policies to allow access to resources.

For example, you can attach the following policies to grant users read-only access to Route 53:

> AmazonRoute53ReadOnlyAccess
>
> AmazonRoute53DomainsReadOnlyAccess

You can also create a policy according to your requirements.

[IAM Policies for Route 53](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/Route53/latest/DeveloperGuide/access-control-managing-permissions.html#access-policy-examples-aws-managed) guide shows few sample policies.

Comment: I granted all policies related to Route53 to the IAM users and still no joy

Comment: It should work for users with administrator rights, unless there is a service-control policy that denies access. If there is no SCP, I'd contact AWS support.